# Private interface methods are supported

Tags: java, interface, java-9, private-methods

[Private interface methods are supported by Java 9.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213)

This support allows non-abstract methods of an `interface` to share code between them. Private methods can be static or instance.

Can private methods of an interface be `abstract` or `default`?

May I ask for an example where "`private static` interface methods" are useful in terms of code?

Comment: You need just 10 seconds to check it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***No***, the private methods in the interfaces are supposedly designed for clubbing in a piece of code that is internal to the `interface` implementation. Since these pertain to the implementation(consist of a body) and not the declaration it can neither be `default` and nor `abstract` when defined.

A `private` method is a `static` method or a non-default instance method that's declared with the `private` keyword. You cannot declare a [`default`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) method to also be `private` because `default` methods are intended to be callable from the classes that implement their declaring interfaces.

---

The `private static` methods are useful in abstracting a common piece of code from `static` methods of an interface while defining its implementation.

Example of a private static method in an interface could be as follows. Consider an object, [`Question.java`](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/internal/src/experiment/Question.java) on StackOverflow defined as:

```
class Question {
    int votes;
    long created;
}
```

and an interface that proposes the sort by functionality as seen in the listed questions on [`StackOverflowTag`](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/internal/src/experiment/StackOverflowTag.java) :

```
public interface StackOverflowTag {

    static List<Question> sortByNewest(List<Question> questions) {
        return sortBy("NEWEST", questions);
    }

    static List<Question> sortByVotes(List<Question> questions) {
        return sortBy("VOTE", questions);
    }

    //... other sortBy methods

    private static List<Question> sortBy(String sortByType, List<Question> questions) {
        if (sortByType.equals("VOTE")) {
            // sort by votes
        }
        if (sortByType.equals("NEWEST")) {
            // sort using the created timestamp
        }
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Here the `private static` method `sortBy` of the interface internally implements the sorting based on the `sortOrderType` sharing the implementation with two public static methods of the interface which can be further consumed by a [`StackOverflowTagConsumer`](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/internal/src/experiment/StackOverflowTagConsumer.java) can simply access these interface static methods as :

```
public class StackOverFlowTagConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Question> currentQuestions = new ArrayList<>();

        // if some action to sort by votes
        displaySortedByVotes(currentQuestions);

        // if another action to sort by newest
        displaySortedByNewest(currentQuestions);
    }

    private static void displaySortedByVotes(List<Question> currentQuestions) {
        System.out.println(StackOverflowTag.sortByVotes(currentQuestions));
    }

    private static void displaySortedByNewest(List<Question> currentQuestions) {
        System.out.println(StackOverflowTag.sortByNewest(currentQuestions));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think that this is a good example. Letting different methods delegate to another method which uses conditionals to tell these callers apart and execute entirely different code dependent on the caller, is the entire opposite of the actual intention, to reuse *common* code.

Comment: @Holger The conditional execution is just an exmple I came up with, of course, the primary intention was to reflect the reusability feature using the `private static` method.

Answer (score 5):

The `default` keyword for interface methods exist, because for interface methods, `abstract` is implicitly assumed if no other modifier contradicts it. Before Java 8, this applied to *all* interface methods, which were always considered `abstract`.

Since the presence of either, `static` or `private`, already implies that it cannot be `abstract` (which applies to ordinary classes as well), there is no need to add a `default` modifier and consequently, Java rules out this combination. And there is no point in asking for this combination either, as `default` merely implies that the method is not `abstract`, technically, so adding it to a method which is already not `abstract` wouldn’t change anything.

On the other hand, since the only methods needing a `default` keyword for declaring that they are not `abstract`, are `public` instance methods, the `default` keyword only applies to overridable methods, which conveniently matches the literal meaning of the word “default”.

`private` methods are useful to provide common operations for the `public` non-`abstract` methods of an interface when these common operations are not supposed to be called from the outside of the interface directly, much like `private` methods in ordinary classes, further, they exist in Java 8 already on the byte code level, as `default` and `static` methods may contain lambda expressions which are compiled into synthetic `private` methods, so there was no technical reason to deny that feature to the Java programming language.

Comment: let then add support for the protected keyword.

Answer (score 2):

No, these three combinations are mutually exclusive. Interface methods cannot be at the same time:

- Default and abstract (because `default` means the opposite of `abstract`)
- Default and private (because you cannot override a private method)
- Abstract and private (because you cannot override a private method)