# Java 9 : default method v/s private method in interfaces

Tags: java, java-9

As everyone knows, Java 9 interfaces will support `private` method also. So now in interfaces you can declare `private` method as well as `default` method. Both the method should have body(I can say it as similarity). I found some questions like this [Java 9: private interface methods, example use-case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040821/java-9-private-interface-methods-example-use-case), didn't found more points.

**As per my understanding I found one differences :**

`default` methods of the interfaces are visible in the subclass, where as `private` method is not visible because of the `private` modifier.

My question is, any other difference are there apart from that?. When we have to go for `private` method and `default` method when designing the API or structure.

Comment: If some **default** method needs a local method, not to be publicized, make that a **private** method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you've got an interface with two `default` methods: `a()` and `b`(). The two methods share some common logic, which you can put in a `private` method `c()`.

In Java8, the above method `c()` would have to be public, even though it's just an internal implementation of the interface. Before the introduction of `private` in interfaces, it was harder to write a clean interface with such default methods.

So you shall mark a method `private` instead of `default` when the implementation that you're about to put in is specific to the interface itself and not to the outside world implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

things have not changed from a logical point of view for me - when were you using `private` methods until now? To hide something? To not duplicate the code? Same things stands here - use it when *you need to*, specifically when there might be code that is *common* for example for multiple other methods, or simply you want to hide it.

Comment: *To hide something? * got this point.

Comment: @ArvindKatte the answer from the link *without exposing that private method and all its "implementation details"* means the same I believe.

Comment: @nullpointer ah! good point - I haven't read that linked question unfortunately. this indeed looks like a duplicate. But sometimes, me including, find better answers in duplicates; still it seems I add close to nothing added value :| you think we should close this one as such?